# Date picker not working

Tags: jquery

hvaing problems getting datepicker to work, not quite sure why.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/jquery-ui-1.8.17.custom.css">
    <!--[if lte IE 7]>
        <style type="text/css">

        </style>
    <![endif]-->
    <script src="js/modernizr-2.0.6.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.ui.core.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.ui.datepicker.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(function() {
        $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
    });
    </script>

<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>
```

I checked and all .js and .css files are linked correctly, however nothing happens, any ideas?

Comment: Looks right. Are you seeing any js errors in the console?

Comment: I'm not sure but you may try it to put your code inside document ready function.

Comment: Do you have any error showed in console?

Comment: How do i view the error console in chrome?

Comment: Right click anywhere in the document and click inspect element then select console tab above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

some thing is wrong with your routes the `jquery` or the `ui` js is not loading, see it working [**HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/yXuqr/), check the firebug console or any other debugging tool for any javascript errors. Try using the cdn hosted jquery and jquery ui, remove

```
    <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.ui.core.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.ui.datepicker.js"></script>
```

and put these inplace

```
http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js
http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/jquery-ui.js
```

Comment: @user195257 so it means the path to your javascript files are not correct

Answer (score 2):

this is how it should be and make sure the routes to the files are correct/existing.

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/jquery-ui-1.8.17.custom.css">
    <!--[if lte IE 7]>
        <style type="text/css">

        </style>
    <![endif]-->
    <script src="js/modernizr-2.0.6.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>

    <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.ui.core.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.ui.datepicker.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
       $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
    });
    </script>

</body>
```

**Edit:**
check out the HTML5 Boilerplate: http://html5boilerplate.com/

Comment: Just asking, why you wrapped $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker() inside another function in ready function ?

Comment: lol, I just noticed that... fixing it now :D... thanks for pointing it out

Comment: use firebug and check the errors in console / open the view page source and try linking on the `.js` files to see if they open and/or gives no error

Comment: @user195257, Did you find any errors on the console ? This code is correct.